# group by comparing 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not very good at MySQL. I don't know how to do the following result. I would be grateful if you help

```
SELECT
   skill ,
   COUNT(*), 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN answer = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS _TRUE, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN  answer <> 'B' OR answer <> 'C'   THEN 1 END) AS _FALSE
FROM tbl_skill_and_answer
WHERE skill = "Text Types" 
GROUP BY skill
```

How can I do this in mysql-php?
My table is as below

My Table

[image]

RESULT

[image: SKILL Number_of_questions True False Test Types 4 3 1]

Comment: without code your question is likely to get closed. Please include the relevant code in your question

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please have another look at `CASE WHEN  answer <> 'B' OR answer <> 'C'   THEN 1 END`, and think about what the output might be if  `answer = 'B'`   (HINT: `CASE WHEN true OR false THEN 1 END` ==> `CASE WHEN true THEN 1 END` )

Comment: If you already solved then you should put an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The asker resolved the issue with the following query (no explanation given):

```
SELECT
   skill, 
   COUNT(*), 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN answer= result THEN 1 END) AS _TRUE, 
   COUNT(CASE WHEN  answer<> result    THEN 1 END) AS _FALSE
   COUNT(CASE WHEN  answer IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS _EMPTY
FROM tbl_skill_and_answer
WHERE skill= "Text Types" 
GROUP BY skill
```